# Migrating a satchmo store from sqlite3 to mysql

Tags: mysql, django, satchmo

I have a fully functional satchmo store running on sqlite3. I need to change to mysql though. Whether I create a new database or port the old database, I get http error 500s in all sorts of places. For example if I have a new db, and I create a user account all seems to be fine. If I then attempt to update the user's profile (which is actually and extended user profile), immediately I get the server 500 error. Its like it just isn't interested in that URL any more (http://127.0.0.1:8000/accounts/update/)

The weird thing is that if I log in as an admin and go to the admin pages, then I can update that user's (extended) profile no problem at all. In fact I've never seen any errors on the admin pages.

Here is how I set it up for mysql:

```
apt-get install mysql-client  
apt-get install mysql-server  
apt-get install python-mysqldb  
mysql -u root -p  
    mysql> USE mysql;  
    mysql> CREATE DATABASE mystore CHARACTER SET utf8;  
    mysql> GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON mystore.* TO storeuser@localhost IDENTIFIED BY 'secret';  
    mysql> FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

settings.py:

```
DATABASE_ENGINE = 'mysql'       
DATABASE_NAME = 'mystore'
DATABASE_USER = 'storeuser'
DATABASE_PASSWORD = 'secret'
DATABASE_HOST = ''         
DATABASE_PORT = ''         
DATABASE_OPTIONS = { "init_command": 'SET NAMES "utf8"' , "init_command":'SET storage_engine=INNODB' , }
```

Then to create a new db I just did ths:

python manage.py syncdb
python manage.py runserver

**Edit 1**

Here is the code where it bombs out:

```
class myExtendedContactInfoForm(ExtendedContactInfoForm):
def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
     # The following line is where it produces the error
    super(myExtendedContactInfoForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
```

**Edit 2**

It seems like there is something missing from the db because if I go back to using a sqlite back-end, and then delete the sqlite db (and then run 'python manage.py syncdb') I get exactly the same symptoms. Seems like I need to do something more than just syncdb.

What am I missing here?

Comment: Are you using a very old version of Django? Those `DATABASE_*` settings haven't been used for several versions.

Comment: dpkg -l | grep django
ii  python-django  1.2.3-3+squeeze3
ii  python-django-registration 0.7-2

Comment: what exception(s) does it raise?

Comment: No exceptions - just the '500' error page is generated.

Comment: @user1294974 It is really important to read the error message and the traceback. You get only the error 500 error page because you did not set neither `ADMIN = ('Your Name', 'your_email@example.com'),)` in settings.py to get it by e-mail or `DEBUG = True` to read it on on the 500 page.